# Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to develop a job site using jobberland scripts.

But on connecting to server the following error shows on all the pages in Firefox:

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Can You help me with the fix please. Is the problem with scripts or with databases (as some sites have explained while I searched on this query).

Comment: Your question is too generic. Add the code that is initiating the redirect so that it can be said why it happens over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

https://shopplugin.net/kb/checkout-redirect-loop-when-https-environment-variable-is-not-set/

Known Cause

Some hosting environments do not declare that they are running securely in a standard way (or at all in some cases). This will cause issues with the is_ssl() to not be set properly. Shopp see’s that SSL is required and then checks for SSL. If is_ssl() is not set, Shopp will attempt to redirect to HTTPS. Thus creating a loop.

The Solution in the link is only for wordpress, but if anyone knows of a generic php fix, please advise!

Comment: This worked for my custom php website.  I added the line: $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = $_SERVER['SSL']; to my primary include.php file and it resolved a problem I'd been having for some time that was eluding me.

Answer (score 2):

This might happen sometimes due to clogged session ( rather invalid cookies in your browser ) or also because of the redirection feature used in server. 
Say for example, the user access Page A, the server might ask the browser to redirect to some Page B by passing on some headers; and based on headers the browser might redirect to a Page B which in turn redirects back to Page A. And it goes on creating an indeterminate loop.

To solve you can try the following:

- Clear your cookies in your browser
- Check the session management and redirection mechanism which you have developed
- Try to clear the server session variables and retry.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's an endless loop (or circular references) caused by HTTP redirection somewhere in the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Like stillstanding said. You have an endlessloop caused either by your php script or by a rewrite rule in your .htaccess or even caused by both.

For example you have a userlogin and if the user is not logged in you redirect any page to `/`.
In index.php you check if the user is loged in and if not you normaly redirect to `/login.php` BUT lets now say you made an error and put a `/user.php` there so that user.php redirects to `/` because the user is not logged in.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue with a PHP page I was working on.  While checking how it rendered in various browsers I got this weird error. I was never able to determine what caused it, the page loaded fine in IE9 + Opera, but gave this error in Firefox.  The script checked for a stored cookie and showed a link based on it, but I wasn't using any redirects or sending any headers from the script.  When the cookie was present in Firefox I got this error, when it wasn't the page loaded fine.  Even after deleting and re-writing the cookie same thing.  I removed Firefox and reinstalled the latest version and the error stopped popping up, so it seemed like something to do with Firefox handling the cookie although I have no idea why.